# Перемена строк

Tags: php

Ребятки, а как поменять отображение строк в php? Есть плагин, который выводит новостной блог, мне необходимо поменять местами дату и заголовок. Всю голову сломала, в упор не понимаю. Всего в плагине 4 документа, один отвечает за вывод интерфейса настроек, стандартных настроек выбора последовательности отображения элементов он не имеет. Пыталась найти в поисковике статью на данную тематику, но не нашла и впала в ступор. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Есть такой код:

```
<?php
/**
 * Various functions used by the plugin.
 *
 * @package    Recent_Posts_Widget_Extended
 * @since      0.9.4
 * @author     Satrya
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2014, Satrya
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */

/**
 * Sets up the default arguments.
 * 
 * @since  0.9.4
 */
function rpwe_get_default_args() {

    $css_defaults = ".rpwe-block h3{\nbackground: none !important;\nclear: none;\nmargin-bottom: 0 !important;\nmargin-top: 0 !important;\nfont-weight: 400;\nfont-size: 12px !important;\nline-height: 1.5em;\n}\n\n.rpwe-block ul{\nlist-style: none !important;\nmargin-left: 0 !important;\npadding-left: 0 !important;\n}\n\n.rpwe-block li{\nborder-bottom: 1px solid #eee;\nmargin-bottom: 10px;\npadding-bottom: 10px;\nlist-style-type: none;\n}\n\n.rpwe-block a{\ndisplay: inline !important;\ntext-decoration: none;\n}\n\n.rpwe-thumb{\nborder: 1px solid #eee !important;\nbox-shadow: none !important;\nmargin: 2px 10px 2px 0;\npadding: 3px !important;\n}\n\n.rpwe-summary{\nfont-size: 12px;\n}\n\n.rpwe-time{\ncolor: #bbb;\nfont-size: 11px;\n}\n\n.rpwe-alignleft{\ndisplay: inline;\nfloat: left;\n}\n\n.rpwe-alignright{\ndisplay: inline;\nfloat: right;\n}\n\n.rpwe-aligncenter{\ndisplay: block;\nmargin-left: auto;\nmargin-right: auto;\n}\n\n.rpwe-clearfix:before,\n.rpwe-clearfix:after{\ncontent: \"\";\ndisplay: table !important;\n}\n\n.rpwe-clearfix:after{\nclear: both;\n}\n\n.rpwe-clearfix{\nzoom: 1;\n}\n";

    $defaults = array(
        'title'             => esc_attr__( 'Recent Posts', 'rpwe' ),
        'title_url'         => '',
        'date'             => true,
        'date_relative'    => false,
        'limit'            => 5,
        'offset'           => 0,
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'cat'              => array(),
        'tag'              => array(),
        'taxonomy'         => '',
        'post_type'        => array( 'post' ),
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky'    => 1,

        'excerpt'          => false,
        'length'           => 10,

        'thumb'            => true,
        'thumb_height'     => 45,
        'thumb_width'      => 45,
        'thumb_default'    => 'http://placehold.it/45x45/f0f0f0/ccc',
        'thumb_align'      => 'rpwe-alignleft',

        'readmore'         => false,
        'readmore_text'    => __( 'Read More &raquo;', 'rpwe' ),

        'styles_default'   => true,
        'css'              => $css_defaults,
        'cssID'            => '',
        'before'           => '',
        'after'            => ''
    );

    // Allow plugins/themes developer to filter the default arguments.
    return apply_filters( 'rpwe_default_args', $defaults );

}

/**
 * Outputs the recent posts.
 * 
 * @since  0.9.4
 */
function rpwe_recent_posts( $args = array() ) {
    echo rpwe_get_recent_posts( $args );
}

/**
 * Generates the posts markup.
 *
 * @since  0.9.4
 * @param  array  $args
 * @return string|array The HTML for the random posts.
 */
function rpwe_get_recent_posts( $args = array() ) {

    // Set up a default, empty variable.
    $html = '';

    // Merge the input arguments and the defaults.
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, rpwe_get_default_args() );

    // Extract the array to allow easy use of variables.
    extract( $args );

    // Allow devs to hook in stuff before the loop.
    do_action( 'rpwe_before_loop' );

    // Display the default style of the plugin.
    if ( $args['styles_default'] == true ) {
        rpwe_custom_styles();
    }

    // If the default style is disbale then use the custom css if it not empty.
    if ( $args['styles_default'] == false && ! empty( $args['css'] ) ) {
        echo '<style>' . $args['css'] . '</style>';
    }

    // Get the posts query.
    $posts = rpwe_get_posts( $args );

    if ( $posts->have_posts() ) :

        $html = '<div ' . ( ! empty( $args['cssID'] ) ? 'id="' . sanitize_html_class( $args['cssID'] ) . '"' : '' ) . ' class="rpwe-block">';

            $html .= '<ul class="rpwe-ul">';

                while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();

                    // Thumbnails
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); // Get the featured image id.
                    $img_url  = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb_id ); // Get img URL.

                    // Display the image url and crop using the resizer.
                    $image    = rpwe_resize( $img_url, $args['thumb_width'], $args['thumb_height'], true );

                    // Start recent posts markup.
                    $html .= '<li class="rpwe-li rpwe-clearfix">';

                        if ( $args['thumb'] ) :

                            // Check if post has post thumbnail.
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                                $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '"  rel="bookmark">';
                                    if ( $image ) :
                                        $html .= '<img class="' . esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb" src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
                                    else :
                                        $html .= '<img class="' . esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb" src="' . esc_url( $img_url ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '" height="' . $args['thumb_height'] . '" width="' . $args['thumb_width'] . '">';
                                    endif;
                                $html .= '</a>';

                            // If no post thumbnail found, check if Get The Image plugin exist and display the image.
                            elseif ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) :
                                $html .= get_the_image( array( 
                                    'height'        => (int) $args['thumb_height'],
                                    'width'         => (int) $args['thumb_width'],
                                    'image_class'   => esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb get-the-image',
                                    'image_scan'    => true,
                                    'default_image' => esc_url( $args['thumb_default'] )
                                ) );

                            // Display default image.
                            elseif ( ! empty( $args['thumb_default'] ) ) :
                                $html .= sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark"><img class="%2$s rpwe-thumb rpwe-default-thumb" src="%3$s" alt="%4$s" width="%5$s" height="%6$s"></a>',
                                    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                                    esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ),
                                    esc_url( $args['thumb_default'] ),
                                    esc_attr( get_the_title() ),
                                    (int) $args['thumb_width'],
                                    (int) $args['thumb_height']
                                );

                            endif;

                        endif;

                        $html .= '<h3 class="rpwe-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" title="' . sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'rpwe' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '</a></h3>';

                        if ( $args['date'] ) :
                            $date = get_the_date();
                            if ( $args['date_relative'] ) :
                                $date = sprintf( __( '%s ago', 'rpwe' ), human_time_diff( get_the_date( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
                            endif;
                            $html .= '<time class="rpwe-time published" datetime="' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'c' ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $date ) . '</time>';
                        endif;

                        if ( $args['excerpt'] ) :
                            $html .= '<div class="rpwe-summary">';
                                $html .= wp_trim_words( apply_filters( 'rpwe_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() ), $args['length'], ' &hellip;' );
                                if ( $args['readmore'] ) :
                                    $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="more-link">' . $args['readmore_text'] . '</a>';
                                endif;
                            $html .= '</div>';
                        endif;

                    $html .= '</li>';

                endwhile;

            $html .= '</ul>';

        $html .= '</div><!-- Generated by http://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-extended/ -->';

    endif;

    // Restore original Post Data.
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Allow devs to hook in stuff after the loop.
    do_action( 'rpwe_after_loop' );

    // Return the  posts markup.
    return $args['before'] . apply_filters( 'rpwe_markup', $html ) . $args['after'];

}

/**
 * The posts query.
 *
 * @since  0.0.1
 * @param  array  $args
 * @return array
 */
function rpwe_get_posts( $args = array() ) {

    // Query arguments.
    $query = array(
        'offset'              => $args['offset'],
        'posts_per_page'      => $args['limit'],
        'orderby'             => $args['orderby'],
        'order'               => $args['order'],
        'post_type'           => $args['post_type'],
        'post_status'         => $args['post_status'],
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => $args['ignore_sticky'],
    );

    // Limit posts based on category.
    if ( ! empty( $args['cat'] ) ) {
        $query['category__in'] = $args['cat'];
    }

    // Limit posts based on post tag.
    if ( ! empty( $args['tag'] ) ) {
        $query['tag__in'] = $args['tag'];
    }

    /**
     * Taxonomy query.
     * Prop Miniloop plugin by Kailey Lampert.
     */
    if ( ! empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) ) {

        parse_str( $args['taxonomy'], $taxes );

        $operator  = 'IN';
        $tax_query = array();
        foreach( array_keys( $taxes ) as $k => $slug ) {
            $ids = explode( ',', $taxes[$slug] );
            if ( count( $ids ) == 1 && $ids['0'] < 0 ) {
                // If there is only one id given, and it's negative
                // Let's treat it as 'posts not in'
                $ids['0'] = $ids['0'] * -1;
                $operator = 'NOT IN';
            }
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => $slug,
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $ids,
                'operator' => $operator 
            );
        }

        $query['tax_query'] = $tax_query;

    }

    // Allow plugins/themes developer to filter the default query.
    $query = apply_filters( 'rpwe_default_query_arguments', $query );

    // Perform the query.
    $posts = new WP_Query( $query );

    return $posts;

}

/**
 * Custom Styles.
 *
 * @since  0.8
 */
function rpwe_custom_styles() {
    ?>
<style>
.rpwe-block h3{background:none!important;clear:none;margin-bottom:0!important;margin-top:0!important;font-weight:400;font-size:12px!important;line-height:1.5em;}.rpwe-block ul{list-style:none!important;margin-left:0!important;padding-left:0!important;}.rpwe-block li{border-bottom:1px solid #eee;margin-bottom:10px;padding-bottom:10px;list-style-type: none;}.rpwe-block a{display:inline!important;text-decoration:none;}.rpwe-thumb{border:1px solid #EEE!important;box-shadow:none!important;margin:2px 10px 2px 0;padding:3px!important;}.rpwe-summary{font-size:12px;}.rpwe-time{color:#bbb;font-size:11px;}.rpwe-alignleft{display:inline;float:left;}.rpwe-alignright{display:inline;float:right;}.rpwe-aligncenter{display:block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}.rpwe-clearfix:before,.rpwe-clearfix:after{content:"";display:table !important;}.rpwe-clearfix:after{clear:both;}.rpwe-clearfix{zoom:1;}
</style>
    <?php
}

и такой:

<?php
/**
 * Widget forms.
 *
 * @package    Recent_Posts_Widget_Extended
 * @since      0.9.4
 * @author     Satrya
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2014, Satrya
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */
?>

<div class="rpwe-columns-3">

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Title', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['title'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title_url' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Title URL', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title_url' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_url' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_url( $instance['title_url'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cssID' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'CSS ID', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cssID' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cssID' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( $instance['cssID'] ); ?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'styles_default' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'styles_default' ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['styles_default'] ); ?> />
        <label class="input-checkbox" for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'styles_default' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Use Default Styles', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'before' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'HTML or text before the recent posts', 'rpwe' );?>
        </label>
        <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'before' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'before' ); ?>" rows="5"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $instance['before'] ) ); ?></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'after' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'HTML or text after the recent posts', 'rpwe' );?>
        </label>
        <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'after' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'after' ); ?>" rows="5"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $instance['after'] ) ); ?></textarea>
    </p>

</div>

<div class="rpwe-columns-3">

    <p>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['ignore_sticky'], 1 ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'ignore_sticky' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'ignore_sticky' ); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'ignore_sticky' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Ignore sticky posts', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
    </p>

    <div class="rpwe-multiple-check-form">
        <label>
            <?php _e( 'Post Types', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <ul>

            <?php foreach ( get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' ) as $type ) : ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $type->name ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_type' ) . '-' . $type->name; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post_type' ); ?>[]" <?php checked( is_array( $instance['post_type'] ) && in_array( $type->name, $instance['post_type'] ) ); ?> />
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_type' ) . '-' . $type->name; ?>">
                        <?php echo esc_html( $type->labels->name ); ?>
                    </label>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_status' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Post Status', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_status' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post_status' ); ?>" style="width:100%;">
            <?php foreach ( get_available_post_statuses() as $status_value => $status_label ) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $status_label ); ?>" <?php selected( $instance['post_status'], $status_label ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( ucfirst( $status_label ) ); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'order' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Order', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'order' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'order' ); ?>" style="width:100%;">
            <option value="DESC" <?php selected( $instance['order'], 'DESC' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Descending', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
            <option value="ASC" <?php selected( $instance['order'], 'ASC' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Ascending', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'orderby' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Orderby', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'orderby' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'orderby' ); ?>" style="width:100%;">
            <option value="ID" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'ID' ); ?>><?php _e( 'ID', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
            <option value="date" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'date' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Date', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
            <option value="author" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'author' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Author', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>

            <option value="title" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'title' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Title', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
            <option value="modified" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'modified' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Modified', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
            <option value="rand" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'rand' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Random', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
            <option value="comment_count" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'comment_count' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Comment Count', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
            <option value="menu_order" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'menu_order' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Menu Order', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <div class="rpwe-multiple-check-form">
        <label>
            <?php _e( 'Limit to Category', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ( get_terms( 'category' ) as $category ) : ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo (int) $category->term_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cat' ) . '-' . (int) $category->term_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cat' ); ?>[]" <?php checked( is_array( $instance['cat'] ) && in_array( $category->term_id, $instance['cat'] ) ); ?> />
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cat' ) . '-' . (int) $category->term_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo esc_html( $category->name ); ?>
                    </label>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="rpwe-multiple-check-form">
        <label>
            <?php _e( 'Limit to Tag', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ( get_terms( 'post_tag' ) as $post_tag ) : ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo (int) $post_tag->term_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tag' ) . '-' . (int) $post_tag->term_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'tag' ); ?>[]" <?php checked( is_array( $instance['tag'] ) && in_array( $post_tag->term_id, $instance['tag'] ) ); ?> />
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tag' ) . '-' . (int) $post_tag->term_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo esc_html( $post_tag->name ); ?>
                    </label>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'taxonomy' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Limit to Taxonomy', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'taxonomy' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'taxonomy' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['taxonomy'] ); ?>" />
        <small><?php _e( 'Ex: category=1,2,4&amp;post_tag=6,12', 'rpwe' );?><br />
        <?php _e( 'Available: ', 'rpwe' ); echo implode( ', ', get_taxonomies( array( 'public' => true ) ) ); ?></small>
    </p>

</div>

<div class="rpwe-columns-3 rpwe-column-last">

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'limit' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Number of posts to show', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'limit' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'limit' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="-1" value="<?php echo (int)( $instance['limit'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'offset' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Offset', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'offset' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'offset' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="<?php echo (int)( $instance['offset'] ); ?>" />
        <small><?php _e( 'The number of posts to skip', 'rpwe' ); ?></small>
    </p>

    <?php if ( current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails' ) ) { ?>

        <p>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumb' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'thumb' ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['thumb'] ); ?> />
            <label class="input-checkbox" for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumb' ); ?>">
                <?php _e( 'Display Thumbnail', 'rpwe' ); ?>
            </label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label class="rpwe-block" for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumb_height' ); ?>">
                <?php _e( 'Thumbnail (height,width,align)', 'rpwe' ); ?>
            </label>
            <input class= "small-input" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumb_height' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'thumb_height' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="<?php echo (int)( $instance['thumb_height'] ); ?>" />
            <input class="small-input" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumb_width' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'thumb_width' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="<?php echo (int)( $instance['thumb_width'] ); ?>"/>
            <select class="small-input" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumb_align' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'thumb_align' ); ?>">
                <option value="rpwe-alignleft" <?php selected( $instance['thumb_align'], 'rpwe-alignleft' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Left', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
                <option value="rpwe-alignright" <?php selected( $instance['thumb_align'], 'rpwe-alignright' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Right', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
                <option value="rpwe-aligncenter" <?php selected( $instance['thumb_align'], 'rpwe-aligncenter' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Center', 'rpwe' ) ?></option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumb_default' ); ?>">
                <?php _e( 'Default Thumbnail', 'rpwe' ); ?>
            </label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumb_default' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'thumb_default' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $instance['thumb_default']; ?>"/>
            <small><?php _e( 'Leave it blank to disable.', 'rpwe' ); ?></small>
        </p>

    <?php } ?>

    <p>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'excerpt' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'excerpt' ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['excerpt'] ); ?> />
        <label class="input-checkbox" for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'excerpt' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Display Excerpt', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'length' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Excerpt Length', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'length' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'length' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="0" value="<?php echo (int)( $instance['length'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'readmore' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'readmore' ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['readmore'] ); ?> />
        <label class="input-checkbox" for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'readmore' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Display Readmore', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'readmore_text' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Readmore Text', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'readmore_text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'readmore_text' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo strip_tags( $instance['readmore_text'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'date' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'date' ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['date'] ); ?> />
        <label class="input-checkbox" for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'date' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Display Date', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'date_relative' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'date_relative' ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['date_relative'] ); ?> />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'date_relative' ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Use Relative Date. eg: 5 days ago', 'rpwe' ); ?>
        </label>
    </p>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'css' ); ?>">
        <?php _e( 'Custom CSS', 'rpwe' ); ?>
    </label>
    <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'css' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'css' ); ?>" style="height:180px;"><?php echo $instance['css']; ?></textarea>
    <small><?php _e( 'If you turn off the default styles, you can use these css code to customize the recent posts style.', 'rpwe' ); ?></small>
</p>

и такой:

<?php

    /*
    *
    *   Swift Page Builder - Blog Items Function Class
    *   ------------------------------------------------
    *   Swift Framework
    *   Copyright Swift Ideas 2014 - http://www.swiftideas.net
    *
    *   sf_blog_items()
    *   sf_blog_aux()
    *
    */

    /* BLOG ITEMS
    ================================================== */ 
    if (!function_exists('sf_blog_items')) {
        function sf_blog_items($blog_type, $masonry_effect_type, $show_title, $show_excerpt, $show_details, $excerpt_length, $content_output, $show_read_more, $item_count, $category, $exclude_categories, $pagination, $sidebar_config, $width, $offset, $posts_order) {

            $blog_items_output = "";

            $options = get_option('sf_dante_options');
            $filter_wrap_bg = $options['filter_wrap_bg'];

            global $sf_sidebar_config;
            $sf_sidebar_config = $sidebar_config;

            /* CATEGORY SLUG MODIFICATION
            ================================================== */ 
            if ($category == "All") {$category = "all";}
            if ($category == "all") {$category = '';}
            $category_slug = str_replace('_', '-', $category);

            /* BLOG QUERY SETUP
            ================================================== */ 
            global $post, $wp_query;

            if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
            $offset = $offset + ($item_count * ($paged - 1));
            } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
            $offset = $offset + ($item_count * ($paged - 1));
            } else {
            $paged = 1;
            }

            $blog_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'category_name' => $category_slug,
                'posts_per_page' => $item_count,
                'cat' => '"'.$exclude_categories.'"',
                'offset' => $offset,
                'order' => $posts_order
                );

            $blog_items = new WP_Query( $blog_args );

            /* LIST CLASS CONFIG
            ================================================== */ 
            $list_class = $wrap_class = '';
            if ($blog_type == "masonry" || $blog_type == "masonry-fw") {
            $list_class .= 'masonry-items first-load grid '.$masonry_effect_type;
            } else if ($blog_type == "mini") {
            $list_class .= 'mini-items';
            } else {
            $list_class .= 'standard-items';
            if ($sidebar_config == "no-sidebars") {
                $wrap_class .= 'col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2';
            }
            }

            /* BLOG ITEMS OUTPUT
            ================================================== */ 
            $blog_items_output .= '<div class="blog-items-wrap blog-'.$blog_type.' '.$wrap_class.'">';
            if ($blog_type == "standard") {
                $blog_items_output .= '<div class="timeline"></div>';
            }
            if ($blog_type == "masonry" || $blog_type == "masonry-fw") {
            $blog_items_output .= '<ul class="blog-items row '. $list_class .' clearfix" id="blogGrid">';
            } else {
            $blog_items_output .= '<ul class="blog-items row '. $list_class .' clearfix">';     
            }

            while ( $blog_items->have_posts() ) : $blog_items->the_post();

                $post_format = get_post_format($post->ID);
                if ( $post_format == "" ) {
                    $post_format = 'standard';
                }

                if ($blog_type == "mini") {
                    $item_class = "col-sm-12";
                } else if ($blog_type == "masonry") {
                    if ($sidebar_config == "both-sidebars") {
                    $item_class = "col-sm-3";
                    } else {
                    $item_class = "col-sm-4";
                    }
                } else if ($blog_type == "masonry-fw") { 
                    $item_class = "col-sm-3";
                } else {
                    $item_class = $width;
                }

                /* BLOG ITEM OUTPUT
                ================================================== */ 
                $blog_items_output .= '<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" class="blog-item '.$item_class.' format-'.$post_format.' '.implode(' ',get_post_class()).'" id="'.get_the_ID().'">';
                $blog_items_output .= sf_get_post_item($post->ID, $blog_type, $show_title, $show_excerpt, $show_details, $excerpt_length, $content_output, $show_read_more);
                $blog_items_output .= '</li>';

            endwhile;

            wp_reset_postdata();

            $blog_items_output .= '</ul>';

            /* PAGINATION OUTPUT
            ================================================== */ 
            if ($pagination == "infinite-scroll") {

                global $sf_include_infscroll;
                $sf_include_infscroll = true;

                $blog_items_output .= '<div class="pagination-wrap hidden">';
                $blog_items_output .= pagenavi($blog_items);                                    
                $blog_items_output .= '</div>';

            } else if ($pagination == "load-more") {

                global $sf_include_infscroll;
                $sf_include_infscroll = true;

                $blog_items_output .= '<a href="#" class="load-more-btn">'.__('Load More', 'swiftframework').'</a>';

                $blog_items_output .= '<div class="pagination-wrap load-more hidden">';
                $blog_items_output .= pagenavi($blog_items);                                    
                $blog_items_output .= '</div>';

            } else if ($pagination == "standard") {
                if ($blog_type == "masonry" || $blog_type == "masonry-fw") {
                $blog_items_output .= '<div class="pagination-wrap masonry-pagination">';
                } else {
                $blog_items_output .= '<div class="pagination-wrap">';
                }
                $blog_items_output .= pagenavi($blog_items);                                    
                $blog_items_output .= '</div>';
            }

            $blog_items_output .= '</div>';

            /* FUNCTION OUTPUT
            ================================================== */
            return $blog_items_output;

        }
    }

    /* BLOG AUX
    ================================================== */ 
    if (!function_exists('sf_blog_aux')) {
        function sf_blog_aux($width) {

            $blog_aux_output = "";
            $options = get_option('sf_dante_options');
            $filter_wrap_bg = $options['filter_wrap_bg'];
            $rss_feed_url = $options['rss_feed_url'];

            $category_list = wp_list_categories('sort_column=name&title_li=&depth=1&number=60&echo=0&show_count=1');
            $archive_list =  wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=12&echo=0');
            $tags_list = wp_tag_cloud('smallest=12&largest=12&unit=px&format=list&number=60&orderby=name&echo=0');

            $blog_aux_output .= '<div class="blog-aux-wrap row">'; // open .blog-aux-wrap
            $blog_aux_output .= '<ul class="blog-aux-options bar-styling '.$width.'">'; // open .blog-aux-options

            // CATEGORIES
            $blog_aux_output .= '<li><a href="#" class="blog-slideout-trigger" data-aux="categories"><i class="ss-index"></i>'.__("Categories", "swiftframework").'</a>';

            // TAGS
            $blog_aux_output .= '<li><a href="#" class="blog-slideout-trigger" data-aux="tags"><i class="ss-tag"></i>'.__("Tags", "swiftframework").'</a>';

            // SEARCH FORM
            $blog_aux_output .= '<li class="search"><form method="get" class="search-form" action="'. home_url().'/">';
            $blog_aux_output .= '<input type="text" placeholder="'. __("Search", "swiftframework") .'" name="s" />';
            $blog_aux_output .= '</form></li>';

            // ARCHIVES
            $blog_aux_output .= '<li><a href="#" class="blog-slideout-trigger" data-aux="archives"><i class="ss-storagebox"></i>'.__("Archives", "swiftframework").'</a>';

            // RSS LINK
            if ($rss_feed_url != "") {
            $blog_aux_output .= '<li><a href="'.$rss_feed_url.'" class="rss-link" target="_blank"><i class="fa-rss"></i>'.__("RSS", "swiftframework").'</a>';
            }

            $blog_aux_output .= '</ul>'; // close .blog-aux-options
            $blog_aux_output .= '</div>'; // close .blog-aux-wrap

            $blog_aux_output .= '<div class="container">';
            $blog_aux_output .= '<div class="filter-wrap slideout-filter blog-filter-wrap row clearfix">'; // open .blog-filter-wrap
            $blog_aux_output .= '<div class="filter-slide-wrap col-sm-12 alt-bg '.$filter_wrap_bg.'">';

            if ($category_list != '') {  
                $blog_aux_output .= '<ul class="aux-list aux-categories row clearfix">'.$category_list.'</ul>';  
            }
            if ($tags_list != '') {  
                $blog_aux_output .= '<ul class="aux-list aux-tags row clearfix">'.$tags_list.'</ul>';  
            }   
            if ($archive_list != '') {  
                $blog_aux_output .= '<ul class="aux-list aux-archives row clearfix">'.$archive_list.'</ul>';  
            }
            $blog_aux_output .= '</div>';

            $blog_aux_output .='</div></div>'; // close .blog-filter-wrap

            /* AUX BUTTONS OUTPUT
            ================================================== */
            return $blog_aux_output;

        }
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется мне, что вот где-то тут надо поменять местами добавление h3 и date.
Если не тут, то значит вы скинули не все файлы.

```
$html .= '<h3 class="rpwe-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" title="' . sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'rpwe' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '</a></h3>';

                    if ( $args['date'] ) :
                        $date = get_the_date();
                        if ( $args['date_relative'] ) :
                            $date = sprintf( __( '%s ago', 'rpwe' ), human_time_diff( get_the_date( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
                        endif;
                        $html .= '<time class="rpwe-time published" datetime="' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'c' ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $date ) . '</time>';
                    endif;
```

Comment: ДААААА! ДАААААА! Спасибо огромное, я вам так благодарна! Целый день с этим возилась.

Comment: Ctrl + F и поиск title и data. Таким образом быстро находится то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @iksuy взял и раскрыл секрет удовлетворения девушек =(